# Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Failure timeout. Using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am trying to invoke an AWS Lambda function to store data in a DynamoDB table. In my own AWS account, it works, but not in the company AWS account I'm working at. CloudWatch does not show any errors. The timeout occurs at `await dynamodb.describeTable(describeParams).promise();`.

[image: .]

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const valueTostore = event.body || 'default_value';

  const params = {
    TableName: 'my-values',
    Item: {
      id: new Date().toISOString(),
      SessionConfig: valueTostore
    }
  };

  try {
    const describeParams = { TableName: 'my-values' };
    await dynamodb.describeTable(describeParams).promise();
  } catch (error) {
    const response = {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Error while accessing table' })
    };
    return response;
  }

  try {
    await docClient.put(params).promise();
  } catch (error) {
    const response = {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Error while storing value' })
    };
    return response;
  }

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Value stored successfully' })
  };
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Is it running in a VPC?

Comment: If the Lambda function is connected to a VPC, is there a specific reason for doing so? If not, disconnect it from the VPC and it will have access to the Internet.

Comment: It’s in a vpc and have to be.

Comment: You have to provide your VPC setup for the lambda. NAT settings, subnets, route tables, etc.

Comment: I set it up in Terraform to use all possible subnets. Do you know how I can debug this so I can find out what is blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Security group for my lambda wasn't configured for outbound rules, so I opened all ports for outbound and it worked! It was a bad error and too broad if AWS sees it, please narrow it down.